# Ubuntu hits a black screen after boot

Tags: 11.10, boot, drivers, fglrx, radeon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I have used wubi.exe to install Ubuntu 11.10 from Windows7.

The OS boots properly most of the time but fails sometimes and hits a blank screen. I could not check any messages on other terminals using "ctrl+alt+F1" as i feel like everything is froze... No keyboard input works.

After searching for sometime, it seems to be a known issue while using Ubuntu with a machine having discrete graphics.

The machines do contain integrated as well as discrete graphics card ATI Radeon 6xxxx

I installed the proprietary driver for ATI using Ubuntu software center but things gone worse. The OS boots and shows up with a black screen all the time. Using recovery mode, I uninstalled the **fglrx** driver and it healed.

Now I let the OS to boot with open source RADEON driver but the blank screen issue occurs at times and freezes.

Tried blacklisting **radeon** and **fglrx** in *modprobe.d/blacklist.conf* file. Rebooting with this didnt solved the problem. Again blank screen. Another reboot, no problem seen, and after few reboots, it again shows up with the problem.

Only solution I had was to set **nomodeset** while booting in the grub entry option. But the screen resolution is not good.

Any help is much appreciated.